# multiple Docker/Singularity containers using same bind mount

Tags: docker, containers, slurm

I have a container that runs a model that takes about 10 hours to run. It requires a lot of input files before it can start, about 2GB. I bind mount these files to the container, like this

```
singularity exec --bind /inputfiles:/app/model image.sif
```

If i want to run, say 1000, instances of the container (using SLURM) each one using the exact same bind mount (for the input files) would you expect issues to arise?

eg.

```
sbatch -N 1 jobx.h  (x = 1, ..., 1000)
```

(here jobx.sh is just a command to run the model)

Would there be cases where multiple containers try to open and read the same files at the same time? Or is something clever occurring in the background, with SLURM, that would prevent this?

I am trying to troubleshoot some strange behaviour i am seeing when running on the cloud and i want to rule out this possible behaviour

Comment: Multiple readers generally isn't a problem. It's when you have multiple processes attempting to *write* to the same file that things get complicated.

Comment: ...but the nature of the bind mount is in fact that every container would be accessing actually the same files, not copies or copy-on-write references.

Comment: @larsks Each container also has an "output" bind mount. All of these "output" locations are in different directories so i dont think there should be any write issues.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that this is a memory issue. The cluster was not managing memory correctly across nodes and aborting the job prematurely.

There is no problem reading the same input files by many containers simultaneously since i tested this by sending 100 jobs to a single node all reading the same input files. All jobs ran successfully